# Multiple tag search using OR operator broken for logged out users

Tags: bug, tags, search

I just noticed an odd bug.

Steps to recreate:

1. Do a search for two tags, using the OR operator.  [Example link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support+or+bug)
2. Observe that it properly returns results that contain either tag.
3. Log out.
4. Do a search for two tags, using the OR operator.  [Example link again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support+or+bug)
5. Observe that you only get results for the first tag, the OR and second tag are stripped out of the search.

Is this a bug, or on purpose for some reason?

Comment: On purpose, following a major DDoS attack. They still didn't "have time to implement a less drastic solution" as Shog says in the official answer.

Comment: repreoed............+1 Edit: looks like @ShadowWizard has a dupe, as always :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ wait... the other one is about sorting, this one here about OR operator. Not sure it's really the same root cause.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Looks like the same cause to me - because you can't actually do the search `[support] or [bug]` as an anonymous user; it just does `[support]`

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ hmm... sure I saw it reported once but just can't find it. Maybe it was really a dupe and OP deleted it. (that's why I always encourage people to keep dupes around and not delete them)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ wow, nice find! Can you please cast a flag? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard don't normally flag as dupes! Be glad to ;p - but a flag doesn't give the OP a binding dupe *close vote* does it? It needs to be one dupe vote first right...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/847/discussion-between-shadow-wizard-and-).