# How do I search with two tags?

Tags: support, tags, tag-search

I have tried searching stack exchange with a combination of two tags, for example [word] [excel], but the actual search defaults to just the first tag. In this case, only [word].

How do I search with multiple tags?

Edit:
From the official FAQ, it sounds like you can search with multiple tags: [Filtering questions by multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17003/filtering-questions-by-multiple-tags)
I just can't get this to work on desktop (chrome, ie11, windows 7)

Edit 2: this a is a duplicate of the below question. I was searching on a work computer while not logged on:
[Multiple tag search using OR operator broken for logged out users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252706/260471)

Comment: You can't search whole Stack Exchange for tags. What site are you talking about?

Comment: Definitely stack exchange. Any subsite (e.g. meta, stack overflow) . for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel - I've been using the search box at the top right on the browser. Tags with square brackets, it just doesn't accept more than one.

Comment: It also sounds like you can search with tags according to the FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17003/filtering-questions-by-multiple-tags

Comment: Ignore previous comment, something else. Anyway, I'm not being able to reproduce. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel+word?sort=active&pageSize=15) give back the single question with both tags, and both tags appear in search box.

Comment: I'm not actually logged in when I'm searching! Thanks! Yes, this means it's a duplicate of the above